# Trying to match two lines of text and return a third in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a couple of different large lists of equipment on seperate worksheets I am trying to consolidate. The first sheet "List" contains multiple columns of information, including one for the area it will be relocated to. Another sheet, "Locations," contains the three areas where each piece of equipment will be relocated to, seperated in to 3 columns; at the top of each column are the names of the locations 2500, 2900, and Term. The issue is, the Equip# from the "List" sheet only partially matches the names on the "Locations" sheet.

List

[image]

Locations

[image]

As you can see above, A2203-76 under Equip# only partially matches A2203-76 20% NAP TANK AGITATOR.

This is the formula I am using {=INDEX(Locations!$A$2:$C$2,,MIN(IF(Locations!A3:C151="A2203-76",COLUMN(Locations!A:C),0)))}. This unfortunately will only return the first column value, which is 2500. What should happen is: First, on the List sheet, the New Gear Location cell should check the Equip# cell in the same row, after retrieving the Equip# it should go to the Locations sheet and search for a partial match to what it retrieved from the Equip# cell. After finding a partial match, it should look at the column the match was found in and return one of the 3 cell values from the top "2500, 2900, or Term" based on what column it was found in and fill this value in the cell on the List page that the formula was entered in to.

Another issue, which makes me think this may not be possible, is there are also instances of A2203-75. So I question if excel has the ability to apply I guess "weights" to different partial matches. What I am getting at is, if I applied some function to partially match A2203-76 to something on the other page, would it just stop at A2203 and pick the A2203-75? Or would it look at the whole string first and find the correct instance? Maybe my thinking is wrong, but if you could offer any help I would appreciate it.

Comment: Well, why not start with left(C3,8) then you can compare just the  equip#...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?:
`=INDEX(Locations!$A:$B,MATCH(List!$A2&"*",Locations!$C:$C,0),COLUMNS($A:A))`

Paste this formula in `List!B2` and drag right, down.
It searches for your search text followed by wildcard `*`.

!! Please note that this will return the first match.
If you are searching for `A2203-76` and your data also contains `A2203-761` it will return this value if it's found prior to `A2203-76` !!